# Why won't MicrosoftAjax.js load over SSL in google chrome on some PCs?

Tags: ssl, google-chrome, cdn, microsoft-ajax

I'm using microsoft's CDN for pulling down the Ajax libraries. And I'm using SSL on some pages.

This URL resolves fine in Firefox and IE:

https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/MicrosoftAjax.js

However in google chrome (on my PC, today...) it seems to time out with a very odd response:
[image]

On other PCs it seems to work fine, however I know I'm not the only one experiencing the problem as we've had occasional complaints from some of our clients about certain pages timing out and failing, that seems to point to the same problem.

Comment: Just now having exactly the same problem except for me, Chrome and IE work and Firefox does not.  Watching fiddler just shows that it was unable to connect, no more useful information.

Comment: For me, Chrome doesn't work, but IE10 does. If I browse to secure version of the link https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/2/WebForms.js in Chrome, it just spins for awhile, then errors out. But if you use the same link with http, it works in Chrome. What the heck is causing this?! Tried emptying cache "since the beginning of time" multiple times in Chrome with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, I experienced the same issue but with Firefox failing and Chrome and IE succeeding.

Restarting the browser and the computer had no affect.  Clearing the browser cache did fix the issue.  I can only assume there was some kind of corruption in the browser cache.